# Writing XML Xpath expression with checking two attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee id="1">
        <age>29</age>
        <name>Pankaj</name>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <role>CEO</role>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="2">
        <age>35</age>
        <name>Lisa</name>
        <gender>Female</gender>
        <role>CEO</role>
    </Employee>
<Employees>
```

How write xpath for getting name whose role is CEO and age is 35?

```
/Employees/Employee[age="35 "]/name/text()
```

The xpath above return name whose age is 35, i need to add condition(role=ceo) to that xpath

Comment: whats the issue you have? do you get errors while trying to generate that? could you please explain more?

Comment: /Employees/Employee[age="35 "]/name/text() , this xpath return name whose age is 35, i need how to add condition(role=ceo) to that xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Add another predicate for `Employee` :

```
/Employees/Employee[age=35][role="CEO"]/name/text()
```

or combine the two conditions in one predicate :

```
/Employees/Employee[age=35 and role="CEO"]/name/text()
```